# Disable auto start of Skype for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, skype-for-windows-10

Before the latest update of Skype on Windows, there was an option under Tools - Settings to "Start Skype when I start Windows". In Skype version 12.1815.210.0 running on my new laptop on Windows 10 Home Single Language, this option is nowhere to be found.

How do I prevent the new Skype from auto-starting when Windows 10 boots up?

Comment: Trigger happy mods like this is why less people ask questions for the fear of being shot down for no reason. Just because I did not find this other question does not prove that I did not research it. I'm not a new user to the SO groups and know how it works. Down voting because I'm not a master at searching for the technically correct phrases is a bit harsh. The numerous views in a few minutes proves that.

Comment: I see no downvoting, actually no voting at all. And marking something as a duplicate is a way to help YOU find help more quickly and efficiently. You can right away read and try the answers already provided instead of waiting for answers in your new question and those might never come or when they do they'll be probably the same. I honestly can't understand why you would have a problem with that.

Comment: There was a -1 which has now mysteriously vanished. I have no reason to make this up. No problem with the duplicate status, I agree 100%. That is cool and will help future searches. Thanks